# http reverse-proxy on one server passing through ssh/socks proxy to second server

Tags: ssh, reverse-proxy, http-proxy, socks

There are some web sites that I can only access from a limited set of machines, but I can ssh into some of these machines (only as a regular user) and use `ssh -D` to set up a SOCKS proxy on my local machine, through which I can access the sites.

What I'd prefer, however, is to be able to go to `http://server.that.i.control/some_path/` (secured in some fashion) and have it be a reverse-proxy through `ssh -D` or something similar on `server.that.i.control`.

Is this doable, preferably with apache or lighttpd on `server.that.i.control`?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Why would the extra ssh step be necessary?  Just set up a reverse proxy on one of the systems that's able to access the site.

Comment: @Shane: I only have user-level access and very limited (if any) ability to put up web pages beyond static stuff on the systems that can actually access the web sites.

Comment: What do you dislike about your current `ssh -D` solution? Might https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle be a better alternative to it than setting up a reverse proxy?

Comment: @sciurus: I dislike having to set up and tear down the ssh connection and change the browser settings or computer networking settings to use the localhost SOCKS proxy just to do maybe 3 page loads.  It's also inconvenient on other people's computers, especially windows boxes that don't necessarily have ssh installed already.  At a glance, I suspect that sshuttle would pose most of the same issues, though I'm thinking there might be a way to use it on the machine that I control to get Apache or lighttpd to do the reverse-proxy stuff.

Comment: yeah, if you used sshuttle on your server you could configure mod_proxy to talk to the web server directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way for apache or lighttpd to use a SOCKS proxy, but I think this is still doable with just ssh and a web server.

There are three servers.

1. your.server
2. gateway.server
3. web.server

*your.server* cannot access websites on *web.server* or ssh to *web.server*. From *your.server* you can ssh to *gateway.server*. From *gateway.server* you can access websites on *web.server*.

First, set up ssh such that when a previously unused port (say, 3000) is accessed the traffic is sent via ssh to *gateway.server* and then via a normal connection to port 80 (or whatever the relevant port is) on *web.server*.

```
[your.server]$ ssh -fnL 3000:web.server:80 gateway.server
```

Second, configure the proxy in apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName your.server
    ProxyPass /some_path http://localhost:3000
    ProxyPassReverse /some_path http://localhost:3000
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain web.server your.server
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /some_path
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, you should be able to access *http://your.server/some_path* and get content from *http://web.server*. You may be done, or another step may be necessary.

The potential flaw in this setup is that the *Host* header will be set to *localhost* when apache on *your.server* connects to *web.server*. If *web.server* host multiple sites and uses the *Host* header to decide what site to return, this won't work. I don't know of a way to have apache's mod_proxy change the *Host* header to something that isn't either the host that the request was made to (*your.server*) or the host of the backend server (which thanks to our ssh tunnel is *localhost*). A hack to work around this would be to edit the hosts file on *your.server* so that the domain names for the sites on *web.server* actually point to *your.server*. Let's say there are two sites you want to access, *site1.web.server* and *site2.web.server*. In */etc/hosts* you would put

```
127.0.0.1 site1.web.server site2.web.server
```

and your apache configuration would change to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName your.server

    ProxyPass /some_path http://site1.web.server:3000
    ProxyPassReverse /some_path http://site1.web.server:3000
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain site1.web.server your.server
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /some_path

    ProxyPass /another_path http://site2.web.server:3000
    ProxyPassReverse /another_path http://site2.web.server:3000
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain site2.web.server your.server
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /another_path
</VirtualHost>
```

To secure access to your reverse proxy, look at [Apache's authentication howto](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html).

Comment: I run into two problems with this setup: (1) I'm unfortunately running Apache 2.0, so I don't have the Cookie commands available [though I don't know what effect, if any, this is having]; (2) the web site I'm most interested in accessing seems to have all its URL references rooted so that while I want everything to end up as `http://your.server/some_path/*`, I'm getting HTML that wants things at `http://your.server/*`, which leads to a very broken web site.

Comment: @Isaac look at http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/ to rewrite the links. I'll edit the answer with details if I get more time today.

Comment: That looks like it'll do the trick; I just haven't had time to deal with installing additional Apache modules to actually try it out.